# Site developed in Codeigniter only loads home page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to move a site developed in Codeigniter from one host to another. The only difference between hosts is that the server the site is moving from is a Windows server (with PHP etc. installed) and the new server is Linux.

However, when I uploaded the site, and changed all the url references, the site only loads the home page.

The address of the new site is http://pioneer.xssl.net/~admin341/

There is a htaccess file, which reads as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

The lines in config.php that relate to the url are:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://pioneer.xssl.net/~admin341/index.php/";
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

Plus the developer (my predecessor) coded a url helper file:

```
function base_url($includeIndexPHP = true)
{       
    if($includeIndexPHP)
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();      
        return $CI->config->slash_item('base_url');
    }
    else
    {
       return 'http://pioneer.xssl.net/~admin341/';
    }
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may well need to change the $config['uri_protocol'] around to get it working on your live site. This is often the cause of the "homepage only" routing issue in CodeIgniter.

The most common is REQUEST_URI but sometimes PATH_INFO works better.

Comment: Thanks Phil. Never come across that before, but works a treat.

Comment: You are great! Banged my head for almost 4 hours before I found this solution. Thanks