# codeigniter only loads home page

Tags: apache, codeigniter

Codeigniter worked fine locally. Once I moved to our actual site it stopped working.
Here is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ~username/folder1/folder2/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

It only loads the index method of the controller and fails to find the other methods.
Also, when I type http://domain.name/~username/folder1/folder2/ControllerClass the index method is not invoked. I have no idea what to do. I have already tried this: [Site developed in Codeigniter only loads home page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4602474/site-developed-in-codeigniter-only-loads-home-page) but it did not work!

Comment: is mod_rewrite installed on your production server?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you edited `$config['base_url']` properly at your config.php.
2. Again inside `config.php`, set `$config['index_page'] = '';`
3. Check out http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite and make sure you did everything as written there.